# TypeError: can't pickle memoryview objects when running basic add.delay(1,2) test

Tags: python-3.x, celery, typeerror, pickle, memoryview

Trying to run the most basic test of add.delay(1,2) using celery 4.1.0 with Python 3.6.4 and getting the following error:

> [2018-02-27 13:58:50,194: INFO/MainProcess] Received task:
>   exb.tasks.test_tasks.add[52c3fb33-ce00-4165-ad18-15026eca55e9]
>   [2018-02-27 13:58:50,194: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error:
>   SystemError(' returned a result with an error set',) Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 624,
>   in _receive_callback
>       return on_m(message) if on_m else self.receive(decoded, message)   File
>   "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py",
>   line 570, in on_task_received
>       callbacks,   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/strategy.py",
>   line 145, in task_message_handler
>       handle(req)   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line
>   221, in _process_task_sem
>       return self._quick_acquire(self._process_task, req)   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/async/semaphore.py",
>   line 62, in acquire
>       callback(*partial_args, **partial_kwargs)   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line
>   226, in _process_task
>       req.execute_using_pool(self.pool)   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/request.py",
>   line 531, in execute_using_pool
>       correlation_id=task_id,   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/concurrency/base.py",
>   line 155, in apply_async
>       **options)   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1486,
>   in apply_async
>       self._quick_put((TASK, (result._job, None, func, args, kwds)))   File
>   "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/concurrency/asynpool.py",
>   line 813, in send_job
>       body = dumps(tup, protocol=protocol) TypeError: can't pickle memoryview objects
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line
>   203, in start
>       self.blueprint.start(self)   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line
>   119, in start
>       step.start(parent)   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line
>   370, in start
>       return self.obj.start()   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py",
>   line 320, in start
>       blueprint.start(self)   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line
>   119, in start
>       step.start(parent)   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py",
>   line 596, in start
>       c.loop(*c.loop_args())   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line
>   88, in asynloop
>       next(loop)   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/async/hub.py", line 354,
>   in create_loop
>       cb(*cbargs)   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py", line
>   236, in on_readable
>       reader(loop)   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/transport/base.py", line
>   218, in _read
>       drain_events(timeout=0)   File "/opt/myapp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/librabbitmq-2.0.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/librabbitmq/**init**.py",
>   line 227, in drain_events
>       self._basic_recv(timeout) SystemError:  returned a result with an error set

I cannot find any previous evidence of anyone hitting this error.  I noticed from the celery site that only python 3.5 is mentioned as supported, is that the issue or is this something I am missing?

Any help would be much appreciated!

UPDATE: Tried with Python 3.5.5 and the problem persists. Tried with Django 4.0.2 and the problem persists.

UPDATE: Uninstalled librabbitmq and the problem stopped. This was seen after migration from Python 2.7.5, Django 1.7.7 to Python 3.6.4, Django 2.0.2.

Comment: I am stuck at the same problem - @dparkeruk , have you found the solution yet?

Answer (score 4):

After uninstalling librabbitmq, the problem was resolved.

Comment: Thanks @dparkeruk, but then you are not using the more performant librabbitmq as amqp is falling but to the slower pyamqp - http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#librabbitmq -- right? Hope you see what i mean